# Serilog with .NET 5 rc1 blazor web assembly not working

Tags: c#, serilog, blazor-webassembly, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

Has anyone been able to get Serilog working with a .NET 5 rc1 blazor web assembly application?

Using the following package references:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0-rc.1.20451.17" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0-rc.1.20451.17" PrivateAssets="all" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0-rc.1.20451.14" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
```

Program.cs logging snippet:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("------------Hello World");
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: What's the problem? Where did you execute this code? On the server side, it should work without any issues. On the client - where do you want to log to begin with? The browser's console? Send the log messages to the server? Perhaps the real question is how to send client events to the server for logging?

Comment: Have you checked the [Blazor WebAssembly logging page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/logging?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the docs?

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all relevant content. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Still work to do to port to RC1: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-browserconsole/issues/9